# How to get timezone from timezone offset in java?

Tags: java, calendar, timezone, timezone-offset, gregorian-calendar

I know how to get the opposite. That is given a timezone I can get the timezone offset by the following code snippet:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
System.out.println(tz.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

I want to know how to get the timezone name from timezone offset.

Given,

`timezone offset = 21600000` (in milliseconds; +6.00 offset)

I want to get result any of the following possible timezone names:

```
(GMT+6:00) Antarctica/Vostok
(GMT+6:00) Asia/Almaty
(GMT+6:00) Asia/Bishkek
(GMT+6:00) Asia/Dacca
(GMT+6:00) Asia/Dhaka
(GMT+6:00) Asia/Qyzylorda
(GMT+6:00) Asia/Thimbu
(GMT+6:00) Asia/Thimphu
(GMT+6:00) Asia/Yekaterinburg
(GMT+6:00) BST
(GMT+6:00) Etc/GMT-6
(GMT+6:00) Indian/Chagos
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`TimeZone#getAvailableIDs(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs(int))

```
import java.util.*;
class Hello
{
   public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
   {
     TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
     int offset = 21600000;
     String[] availableIDs = tz.getAvailableIDs(offset);
     for(int i = 0; i < availableIDs.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(availableIDs[i]);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: That's nice! Are there any pitfalls using this strategy? I mean DST (Daylight Saving Time) related things?

Comment: The following link might help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Be aware that this only returns entries whose *standard time* offset matches.  For example, passing `-25200000` doesn't return `America/Los_Angeles`, which uses that offset during daylight saving time.

Comment: Why are you using `TimeZone.getDefault()` at all? This code would be better as `String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIds(21600000L);`. Avoid calling static methods as if they were instance methods.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet. And thank you. Matt Johnson. Your comments are useful.

Comment: One question, if I change the default timezone from one thread will it affect other threads? @JonSkeet

Comment: @AnonymousOne: I believe so, yes.

Comment: Why don't we use sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo offset = (ZoneInfo) timezone.getDefault(); directly? It will give us timezone info directly like "Asia/Almaty" by .getID() method.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
List < String > names =
        ZoneId
                .getAvailableZoneIds()
                .stream()
                .filter(
                        ( String name ) ->
                                ZoneId
                                        .of( name )
                                        .getRules()
                                        .getOffset( instant )
                                        .equals(
                                                ZoneOffset.ofHours( 6 )
                                        )
                )
                .collect( Collectors.toList() )
;
```

In Java 14.0.1:

> names = [Asia/Kashgar, Etc/GMT-6, Asia/Almaty, Asia/Dacca, Asia/Omsk, Asia/Dhaka, Indian/Chagos, Asia/Qostanay, Asia/Bishkek, Antarctica/Vostok, Asia/Urumqi, Asia/Thimbu, Asia/Thimphu]

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy date-time classes. Specifically, `TimeZone` was replaced by:

- [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html)
- [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html)
- [`ZoneRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html)

An offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead of or behind the prime meridian. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history fo the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. A time zone has a name in `Continent/Region` format. See [list of zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Get the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)’s current time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

Get a list of all `ZoneId` objects currently defined. Be aware that time zones are frequently changed by politicians. So this list, and the rules they contain, will change. Keep your [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) up-to-date.

```
Set< String > zones = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds() ;
```

You asked:

> I want to know how to get the timezone name from timezone offset.

Many time zones may coincidentally share the same offset at any given moment. In code below, we loop all known time zones, asking each for its offset.

Since time zone rules change over time (determined by politicians), you must provide a moment for which you want the offset in use by each zone. Here we use the current moment at runtime.

```
// Convert your milliseconds to an offset-from-UTC.
int milliseconds = 21_600_000;
int seconds = Math.toIntExact( TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds( milliseconds ) );
ZoneOffset targetOffset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds( seconds );

// Capture the current moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).
Instant now = Instant.now();

// Loop through all know time zones, comparing each one’s zone to the target zone.
List < ZoneId > hits = new ArrayList <>();
Set < String > zoneNames = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
for ( String zoneName : zoneNames )
{
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( zoneName );

    ZoneRules rules = zoneId.getRules();
    // ZoneRules rules = zoneId.getRules() ;
    ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( now );
    if ( offset.equals( targetOffset ) )
    {
        hits.add( zoneId );
    }
}
```

Dump to console. See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/wmiMdN).

```
// Report results.
System.out.println( "java.version " + System.getProperty("java.version") ) ;
System.out.println( "java.vendor " + System.getProperty("java.vendor") ) ;
System.out.println() ;
System.out.println( "targetOffset = " + targetOffset );
System.out.println( "hits: " + hits );
```

See this code run live at IdeOne.com.

> java.version 12.0.1
>
> java.vendor Oracle Corporation
>
> targetOffset = +06:00
>
> hits: [Asia/Kashgar, Etc/GMT-6, Asia/Almaty, Asia/Dacca, Asia/Omsk, Asia/Dhaka, Indian/Chagos, Asia/Qyzylorda, Asia/Bishkek, Antarctica/Vostok, Asia/Urumqi, Asia/Thimbu, Asia/Thimphu]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).