# How to get time zone from offset

Tags: android, kotlin, timezone, timezone-offset

I am getting offset time like 180000 from API, but what I need is time zone like newYork/America ,how can I get time zone from offset , is there any method. Any help would be appreciated. I am calculating time from time Epoch like this

```
fun Int.currentConverter(): String {
    val time = SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM, hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH)
    return time.format(this * 1000L)
}
```

Comment: 180000, are they milliseconds, seconds, minutes, are they 18 hours 00 minutes 00 seconds, what are they?? In any case you can’t since many time zones generally share the same offset at a given point in time.

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get timezone from timezone offset in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184908/how-to-get-timezone-from-timezone-offset-in-java). Search for more.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add timezone in your function and try once

```
 fun Date.currentConverter(): String {
    var localFormat="d MMMM, hh:mm a"
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(localFormat,, Locale.ENGLISH)
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")
          return formatter.format(this)
    }
```

Comment: @Josh it works fine but I want to time according to time zone , but the problem is my API does not provide me with time zone instead it provides me with offset time

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(
            TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"),
            Locale.getDefault()
        )
        val currentLocalTime = calendar.time
        val date: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("Z")
        val localTime: String = date.format(currentLocalTime)
```